# Properties of Independent Events

Tags: probability

Let A be an event such that P[A] ∈ (0, 1). Show that A and AC are not independent. Does this still hold if P[A] ∈ {0, 1}?

The solution is: We have P[A∩A^C] = P[∅] = 0. On the other hand, P[A]·P[A^C] = PA. The events are independent if, and only if, these two quantities are equal, i.e., if, and only if, P[A] = 0 or P[A] = 1.

Are the events independent, because for both P[A] = 0 or 1, P[A]·P[A^C] = PA = 0?

Comment: You have several errors and mistakes in typesetting this.  For example you say "*On the other hand, `P[A]·P[A^C] = PA`.*"  What do you mean by `PA`?  That does not match the notation you have been using till now.  You should have found $\Pr(A)\cdot\Pr(A^c)=\Pr(A)\cdot(1-\Pr(A))$ which you should know is equal to zero iff $\Pr(A)$ is zero or $\Pr(A)=1$.

Comment: The punchline is that mutually exclusivity is not the same as mutual independence, and that you can not have events be both except in the extreme cases of either (*almost*) impossible events (*probability zero*) or (*almost*) sure events (*probability 1*).